# what if given answer is correct but I solved the problem before, should I accept the answer?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I have posted a question and after a while I solved it my own, but somebody also posted an answer on my question which is correct. Should I accept the answer or update my question?

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, why don't you *write your own answer*? You can still upvote that other answer if you think it's useful, but if you didn't actually use it you shouldn't accept it.

Comment: Why not @jon? Is there any point adding a second, identical, answer when the one already there answers the question.

Comment: Oh, I'd assumed that your own solution was *different* to the one that's been posted by somebody else. If it's the same as the answer you'd have written, by all means just accept it.

Answer (score 7):

YES if it is the same solution as yours and you didn't write your own answer already

NO if you used a different approach.

In any case upvote it if it could be helpful to others.

Also please let a question stay a question, just modify it if you want to make it clearer to others, so people can search for questions too not only for solutions!

If you have the time to elaborate the solutions, to find out which one is better, do it and eventually change the accepted answer accordingly, with a comment.

Just my opinion on how it should be done.